# Physical intuition behind the optical theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, s-matrix-theory, unitarity, scattering-cross-section, intuition

I am taking a course of QM (as part of my maths studies) and we saw the [optical theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_theorem) in scattering theory. Namely, we have $$\sigma = \frac{4\pi}{k}\Im f(\vec{q}=0),$$ where $\sigma$ is the total cross section  and $f$ the scattering amplitude.

Mathematically, how we derived this formula is pretty clear to me. However, I am struggling with the physical interpretation of this result. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We expect something linear in $f$. But if $f(0)$ is real, we don't have the phase mismatch needed to scatter, so the answer should be proportional to $\Im f(0)$. The $4\pi$ factor from geometry has an obvious meaning, while dimensional analysis demands a $k^{-1}$ factor ($f$ is a length, $k$ a wavenumber, $\sigma$ an area).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It makes it more clear! Could you elaborate a little bit on the phase mismatch though, please?

Comment: @Spida When scattering results from adding two terms, if they're parallel or antiparallel (as happens when $\Im f(0)=0$) the calculation is $1$-dimensional, so scattering through an angle doesn't occur.

Comment: All good, thank you!